# Listview gives wrong data when clicked

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I am new to android programming and I have encountered a problem...

When I clicked an item in the listview, I am being given the wrong item.

Here's a part of the code:

```
on the DBHelper:

 //view all
 public ArrayList getAll()
 {
   ArrayList array_list = new ArrayList();
   SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
   Cursor res =  db.rawQuery( "SELECT * FROM member", null );
   res.moveToFirst();
   while(res.isAfterLast() == false){
   array_list.add(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(MEMBER_COLUMN_NAME)));
   res.moveToNext();
   }
   return array_list;
   } //view all

 // view all where status is not equal to 1
 public ArrayList getStat()
 {
   ArrayList al_stat = new ArrayList();
   SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
   Cursor cur =  db.rawQuery( "SELECT * FROM member WHERE status <> 1", null );
   cur.moveToFirst();
   while(cur.isAfterLast() == false){
   al_stat.add(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(MEMBER_COLUMN_NAME)));
   cur.moveToNext();
   }
 return al_stat;
 } //view all where selected is not equal to 1
```

and here's a part of VIEWSTAT ACTIVITY:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_reset);

      mydb = new DBHelper(this);
      ArrayList al_stat = mydb.getStat();

      ArrayAdapter arAdapter =      
      new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, al_stat);

      //adding it to the list view.
      stat = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvStat);
      stat.setAdapter(arAdapter);

      stat.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

          @Override
         public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int args2,
         long arg3) {
             // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             int idStat = args2 + 1;
             Bundle dtBundle = new Bundle();
             dtBundle.putInt("id", idStat);
             Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ViewMemberInfo.class);
             intent.putExtras(dtBundle);
             startActivity(intent);
         }
         });
      }
```

I am using the first class in an activity to view all members and its working perfectly. Clicking an item, gives me the right person/position.

The second class, I am using in a different activity to view members whose status is not equal to 1.
The sql is working, but when I click the item in the listview, it is not giving/showing the right member.

```
Example:
In the VIEWALL ACTIVITY, I have:
Member Name:
   Juan Cruz
   Anna Marcos
   Luke Santos
   Mark San Jose

In VIEWSTAT ACTIVITY, I have:
Member Name:
   Anna Marcos
   Luke Santos
   Mark San Jose
```

For Example, I clicked "Anna Marcos", The member info that is shown is that of "Juan Cruz", and so on...

Reiterating the question: When I click an item in the VIEWSTAT ACTIVITY, it is giving me the item/info above the item that I selected/clicked. What did I miss?

Thank you for the help.

Comment: int idStat = args2 + 1;, are you sure the id is always position + 1? args2 is the clicked position

Comment: no Sir I'm not. How can I fix it then? >.<

Answer (score 0):

You can get the Object in your ArrayAdaptor at the position clicked

```
Object o = arg0.getItemAtPosition(args2);
```

`arg0` is the adaptor and `args2` is the position index

Answer (score 0):

As you said in the comment, `int idStat = args2 + 1;` is a wrong logic.

You need to do something like this :

```
      @Override
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int args2,
     long arg3) {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         int idStat =arAdapter.getItem(args2).getId();
         Bundle dtBundle = new Bundle();
         dtBundle.putInt("id", idStat);
         Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ViewMemberInfo.class);
         intent.putExtras(dtBundle);
         startActivity(intent);
     }
     });
```

The point is, you need to get the ID of people (by using their `getter`) with `arAdapter` (your `listview's` adapter).

**Hence**, `arAdapter.getItem(args2).getId();` means get the ID of the person based on the clicked position.

Comment: adding the code, gives me errors which I fix because of the hints. the code became int idStat = ((View) arAdapter.getItem(pos)).getId(); but it gives errors that are not available for view in the LogCat

Answer (score 0):

Why are youa adding 1 in args2 ?This is basically the POSITION of item clicked.So it will become the index or position number of your arraylist.Let suppose
ArrayList al_stat = mydb.getStat();

Suppose that Al_stat after getting value from db is like this : 
Al_stat={"John","Miller","Muhammad"};
So Now john is at position 0,
Miller at position 1 ,
Muhammad At position 2, 
You give this arrayList to the Listview , and whenever an item is clicked it return the position number 
So if arg2 gives u 0, Al_stat.get(0) will give u john,
But you are adding 1 to args 2,  So if john is clicked , You are doing this 
Args 2 +1=1; So you will get Miller instead of john

Answer (score 0):

Your actual problem is you probably want to pass the database id but to do that you have to save it in your array adapter.  **If you didn't add one in your onclick handler your app would work.**  It's pretty obvious but Dude there are so many more errors with your code so pay attention and you can get this working.

delete these as soon as you start coding the method.

```
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
```

Meaningful names

```
public void onItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
```

Don't select * from table it's wasteful on any system large or small and it will in the future cause problems when you alter tables.

```
SELECT mycol, myIdcol FROM member
```

Every loop your calling the `getColumnIndex` function call it once outside of the read loop.  I know how easy it is to chain out and embed functions within functions but in a loop you have to do only essential code for that loop.

how about a simpler faster loop that will make your app rock?  `moveToNext()` will automatically do a `moveToFirst()` for you when it is called after the database is opened.

```
int colName = res.getColumnIndex(MEMBER_COLUMN_NAME);
while (res.moveToNext()){
    al_stat.add(cur.getString(colName));
}
```

Or if you must have a `moveToFirst()`

```
if (moveToFirst){
    do {
        al_stat.add(cur.getString(colName));
    } while (moveNext());
}
```

In my code I go back to the adapter and get the item and send it with the intent so I don't have to hit the database again.  Your code might can be different and send just an int and then hit the database.

```
myitem = adapter.getItem(position);
Bundle extras = new Bundle();
extras.putParcelable("myItem",myitem);
intent.putExtras(extras);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: thank you, and sorry for the issues in the code, as I said I am new to android programming and I am just looking for answers from the Internet. though t'was a mistake that I have been relying much on it. they seem to be working and they're all the same so I thought it was ok. Thank you for the tips. and im not a dude. ^_^

Comment: Dude is now general neutral.